# Array.filter() in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller

I'm trying to filter through an array of objects in a controller using the JavaScript `filter()` method. I get an error, however, that says,

> Uncaught Action failed: c:QuestionIteration$controller$handleClick [questionArray.filter is not a function]

Here's the code:

```
getQuestionName : function (component, event, helper) {
    let questionArray = JSON.stringify(component.get("v.questions"));
    let questionName = questionArray.filter(x => x.Id).map(x => x.Name);
    console.log(`questionName: ${questionName}`;}
}
```

questionArray returns an array of objects that looks like this

```
   questionArray = [{
        "Id": "a0Z2C000000ZBX8UAO",
        "Name": "FFSQ-0011",
        "FFS_Key_Area__c": "Communications 1",
        "Department_Lookup_Name__c": "Communications"
    },

    {
        "Id": "a0Z2C000000ZBXDUA4",
        "Name": "FFSQ-0012",
        "FFS_Key_Area__c": "Communications 2",
        "Department_Lookup_Name__c": "Communications"
    },

    {
        "Id": "a0Z2C000000ZBXIUA4",
        "Name": "FFSQ-0013",
        "FFS_Key_Area__c": "Communications 3",
        "Department_Lookup_Name__c": "Communications"
    }
];
```

The filter is successful outside of Salesforce when running in my browser after I've copied the array of objects.

Comment: FYI, watch out that `let` is [not fully implemented in IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are turning your array into a string:

```
let questionArray = JSON.stringify(component.get("v.questions"));
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                            ^
```

If `v.questions` is an array, just cache it as such. Also use `const` since you don't reassign:

```
const questionArray = component.get("v.questions");
```